# Named requirement for std::tuple-like?

Tags: c++, tuples, stdtuple

I was making a generic hash algorithm for `std::tuple`, and realised I could make it work for `std::pair` and `std::array` as well, as these three classes implement `std::tuple_size` and `std::get`. Is this "standardised" anywhere? Is there a "`std::allocator_traits`" but for std::tuple-like classes instead of std::allocator-like classes?

Currently I am doing this to check if a class is "tuple-like":

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <cstddef>
#include <utility>
#include <tuple>

namespace is_tuple {
    namespace detail {
        // T* exists for incomplete types, but not sizeof(T)
        template<class T, ::std::size_t = sizeof(T)>
        ::std::true_type is_complete_type_impl(T*);

        ::std::false_type is_complete_type_impl(...);

        template<class T>
        struct is_complete_type : decltype(
            is_complete_type_impl(::std::declval<T*>())
        ) {};
    }

    template<class T>
    struct is_tuple : detail::is_complete_type<::std::tuple_size<T>>::type {};
}
```

This might have some false positive (though I don't think it does)

These are the "requirements" I am imposing for "tuple-like" types, for a type `T` and an object of type `T` called `t`:

1. `std::tuple_size<T>` is a complete type
2. `std::tuple_size<T>::value` is a `static constexpr const std::size_t` (called `N`)
3. `std::get<I>(t)` returns non-void for all `I` in [`0`, `N`)

(Is this correct and complete? I also implemented checking `std::get`, but the code was too long to post)

And also, is there a better way to specify if a type is "tuple-like" other than specialising `std::tuple_size<T>` (Something like an iterator_tag maybe)

Comment: checking for `std::get<i>` should be checking for `get<i>`, since the candidate should be found via ADL

Comment: `std::tuple_element` might be missing (needed for *Structured binding* for example) (and allow to handle reference types: `std::get<0>(std::tie(lvalue))` and `std::get<0>(std::make_tuple(lvalue))` both returns reference type).

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot: `t.get<I>()` is also possible for [structured_binding](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding).

Answer (score -1):

> Is this "standardised" anywhere?

If you mean the hash algorithm, then (like so many things) there is already a complete solution in `boost`.

`boost` is of course, arguably *more standardised* and certainly *more portable* than the various **implementations** of the c++ standard itself.<sup>1</sup>

```
#include <boost/functional/hash.hpp>
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>
#include <array>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

template<class T>
std::size_t hashit(T const& x)
{
    using x_type = std::decay_t<T>;
    return boost::hash<x_type>()(x);
}

template<class T>
std::size_t hashit2(T const& x)
{
    using boost::hash_value;
    return hash_value(x);
}

int main()
{
    using namespace std::literals;

    std::cout << hashit(std::make_tuple(1, 2, 5, "foo"s)) << '\n';
    std::cout << hashit2(std::make_tuple(1, 2, 5, "foo"s)) << '\n';

    std::cout << '\n';

    std::cout << hashit(std::make_pair(1.0, 2.0)) << '\n';
    std::cout << hashit2(std::make_pair(1.0, 2.0)) << '\n';

    std::cout << '\n';

    std::cout << hashit(std::array<int, 3>{4, 5, 6}) << '\n';
    std::cout << hashit2(std::array<int, 3>{4, 5, 6}) << '\n';
}
```

<sup>1</sup> This will be seen by many as a controversial statement. It is nonetheless empirically true.

Comment: So how would I get this to work with my own class? Just define `get` in the same namespace and `std::tuple_size`?

Comment: Answer completely misses the OP's question.  He's happy with his own hash implementation.  He wants to know how to get/supply tuple-ish "traits".

Comment: @Artyer if by "work" you mean "produce reasonable hash values" then you would simply write an overload of `hash_value()` for your class in the same namespace as your class. Boost does the rest. You would write `hash_value()` in terms of `hash_value()`, `boost::hash<>`, `boost::hash_combine()` and so on.
https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/doc/html/hash/custom.html

Comment: @davidbak The usual reason people start to write generic hash algos for tuples and containers is because (a) the c++ shockingly standard leaves them high and dry on this subject, and (b) because they don't realise that the nice people at boost have already come to the rescue in the most splendid way.

Comment: @RichardHodges - I'm sure you're right.  I also know from my own experience that when working on some other problem you sometimes come across something else you'd like to know, independently.  That is, even though you wouldn't _need_ to know it to solve the original problem, had someone suggested an alternative solution to that original problem, it's something you still _want_ to know.  And this OP apparently wants to know about tupleish traits, which is the total focus of this question.