# C++20 Concept to check tuple-like types

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

I'd like to create a concept for tuple-like types. A tuple-like type would be something that, like `std::pair`, `std::tuple` and `std::array`, offers a compile time known number of types accessible through a compile time indexed `get<size>` function.

I am new to concepts and I do not know where to start. Unfortunately, the STL seems not to have such a concept in the `<concepts>` header.

For example, I can write:

```
template<typename T>
concept tuple_like = requires(T value)
{
    std::invoke(get<0>, value);
};
```

But I am not sure how to generalize that `0` to be any index.

Comment: It's not any index, though, since there is a maximum index.

Comment: This is a dupe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54100247/named-requirement-for-stdtuple-like but it doesn't have an upvoted/accepted answer.

Comment: @cigien I'd argue is a duplicate cause the OP there is not trying to use C++20 Concepts to achieve the goal (though the goal is the same)

Comment: I think it's still a dupe, because concepts are just syntactic sugar, but I actually wouldn't mind closing that one as a dupe of this one if this gets a decent answer. I'll follow this question, and if it's answered, I'll hammer the questions accordingly.

Comment: @cigien maybe, but if I get for example two answers, one is using type traits and sfinae, the other one is using concepts, I'll flag as best answer the second one even if it is just syntactic sugar `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: I understand, and that's reasonable. The issue is that there are quite a few questions on SO asking "how to check X?" where concepts are not mentioned at all (because they didn't exist back then). I don't think we need *separate* questions for the concepts versions in general; the modern concept based solution should be added on the target itself. The only reason I'm not closing this one as dupe is because I can't as the system doesn't allow it.

Comment: [structured_binding tuple-like_type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding#Case_2:_binding_a_tuple-like_type) might provide possible requirements. just turn them into concepts/traits.

Comment: @Jarod42 Indeed those are basically the requirements. But as I mentioned in the question, I have no clue how to turn all of them into a proper `concept`.

Comment: Check for `std::tuple_size`, it is defined for all tuple-like classes.

Comment: @Jarod42. There is [no way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63369361/how-to-define-a-concept-of-a-object-that-is-can-be-structured-binding) to define a `concept` like that.

Comment: @康桓瑋: The answer from the link actually says it is not possible for aggregate types, but probably possible for tuple-like types. So we are fine.

Answer (score 10):

The standard defines exposition only concept *`pair-like`* and *`has-tuple-element`* in [[range.subrange]](http://eel.is/c++draft/range.subrange) and [[range.elements.view]](http://eel.is/c++draft/range.elements.view) respectively, we can extend them to the *`tuple-like`* concept

```
template<class T, std::size_t N>
concept has_tuple_element =
  requires(T t) {
    typename std::tuple_element_t<N, std::remove_const_t<T>>;
    { get<N>(t) } -> std::convertible_to<const std::tuple_element_t<N, T>&>;
  };

template<class T>
concept tuple_like = !std::is_reference_v<T> 
  && requires(T t) { 
    typename std::tuple_size<T>::type; 
    requires std::derived_from<
      std::tuple_size<T>, 
      std::integral_constant<std::size_t, std::tuple_size_v<T>>
    >;
  } && []<std::size_t... N>(std::index_sequence<N...>) { 
    return (has_tuple_element<T, N> && ...); 
  }(std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size_v<T>>());
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/GM5re9Wjx)

Please be sure to check out [P2165R2](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p2165r2.pdf) which also defines a similar *`tuple-like`* concept.

Comment: "*derived_from*" Why does `tuple_size` have to be derived from anything? Using `tuple_size_v` will automatically require that `tuple_size<T>::value` is a compile-time constant. Also, checking for `std::get` instead of ADL-based `get` is not a good idea.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas. "*Why does tuple_size have to be derived from anything?*" The standard describes in [tuple#helper-1](http://eel.is/c++draft/tuple#helper-1): "All specializations of `tuple_size` meet the *Cpp17UnaryTypeTrait* requirements ([meta.rqmts]) with a base characteristic of `integral_constant<size_t, N>` for some `N`."

Comment: Do we really need both typename std::tuple_size<T>::type; and requires std::derived_from<...>? Doesn't the second already implies the first one?

Answer (score 0):

I think, a tuple-like type is a class for which both `std::tuple_size` and `std::get` are defined.

Here is an example of how this can be conceptualized:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <array>

template<typename T>
concept TupleLike =
requires (T a) {
    std::tuple_size<T>::value;
    std::get<0>(a);
};


template<TupleLike T>
void foo(T t);


std::tuple<int, char> t1;
std::array<int, 10> a1;

void bar()
{
    foo(t1); // OK
    foo(a1); // OK

    foo("Hello"); //Fails
}
```

Please note, this will fail for empty tuples, which might be what you want, or might not.

Comment: `std::tuple<>` is not `TupleLike` with your definition...

Comment: @Jarod42 yes, I was going to add it just now

Comment: I think `get<0>` is not enough, it should be possible to get any index < `tuple_size`

Comment: Understanding [structured bindings](//en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding) and translating that into a `concept` is the way to go...

Comment: Instead of looking up `std::get<0>`, you should be looking up `get<0>` by argument-dependent lookup (only). E.g. for a user-defined type `NS::TupleLike`, the relevant overload is `NS::get`. Even if the user provides their own overload of `std::get`, it won't be used by structured binding. (This makes intuitive sense, because the Standard _never_ encourages users to add their own function overloads into `namespace std`. Class and variable template specializations yes, functions never.)

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time I just do this:

```
template<typename T>
concept TupleLike = requires{std::tuple_size<T>::value;};
// Can't use `std::tuple_size_v` as it's not SFINAE-friendly.
```

If something else is missing, you'll get a hard error, yes. But I don't see it as a problem, since arguably a type with an incomplete implementation of the tuple protocol is broken anyway.

One thing to note is that you must use `using std::get;` `get<i>(t)` instead of `std::get<i>(t)` to support user-defined types that have `get()` in their namespace rather than in `std::`. This is what C++17 structured bindings do internally.