# C++ transform std::pair<std::pair<std::pair<A, B>, C>, D> to std::tuple<A, B, C, D>

Tags: c++, templates, tuples, c++20

I have such kind of code:

```cpp
const auto temp = std::make_pair(std::make_pair(std::make_pair('Q', 1.2),
    std::string("POWER")), 1);
std::cout << std::format("({}, {}, {}, {})\n", temp.first.first.first, 
    temp.first.first.second, temp.first.second, temp.second);
```

that obviously prints:

```
(Q, 1.2, POWER, 1)
```

I want to make it more readable and intuitive by converting "pair of pair and smth" to `std::tuple`:

```cpp
const auto temp = std::make_pair(std::make_pair(std::make_pair('Q', 1.2),
    std::string("POWER")), 1);
const auto tuple = PairsToTuple(temp);

std::cout << std::format("({}, {}, {}, {})\n", std::get<0>(tuple),
    std::get<1>(tuple), std::get<2>(tuple), std::get<3>(tuple));
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't `const auto temp = std::tuple('Q', 1.2, "Power", 1)` in the first place?

Comment: If you want your code to become more readable, don't use pair or tuple. Create a proper datastructure with classes and functions (getters) with meaningful names. Reviewing/maintining code using, ->first, ->second is very tedious because they are not self-describing. Code should have an abstraction level that describes WHAT it is doing not HOW (unless it hinders perfomance too much).

Comment: @Caleth Its better, but it is still not very clear what the tuple represents.  A struct with clearly named members would IMO much more maintainable.

Comment: @Caleth Yes, I use pair of pairs 'cause it feets to my idea of variaic template cartesian product realization where I can easly use recursion and reduction to cartesian product of two ranges, then result of it product with another range etc.

I don't know, maybe this solution isn't good, 'cause I'm newbie in metaprograming.

Comment: @PepijnKramer if you are just going to shove it into a structured binding, then it's less bad. Something like `for (auto [x, y, z] : product(xs, ys, zs))`

Comment: Also true.. but only for a local scope 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can recursively `std::tuple_cat`

```
template<typename First, typename Second>
auto flatten(std::pair<First, Second> pair) {
    return std::tuple_cat(flatten(pair.first), flatten(pair.second));
}

template<typename... Types>
auto flatten(std::tuple<Types...> tup) {
    return std::apply([](auto... args) { return std::tuple_cat(flatten(args)...);}, tup);
}

template<typename T>
auto flatten(T t) {
    return std::tuple{ t };
}
```

[See it on coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/40f3705252c9b2d8)

If you have C++20, we can generalise this to anything tuple-like with a [concept](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68443804/c20-concept-to-check-tuple-like-types):

```
template<typename T>
auto flatten(T&& t) {
    if constexpr (tuple<std::remove_cvref_t<T>>) {
        return [&]<std::size_t... Is>(std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
            return std::tuple_cat(flatten(get<Is>(std::forward<T>(t)))...);
        }(std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size_v<std::remove_cvref_t<T>>>{});
    } else {
        return std::tuple{ std::forward<T>(t) };
    }
}
```

[See it on coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1b521a65dd43bcb4)

Comment: Why do you need the `std::tuple` overload?

Comment: Thank you for quick answer, it works perfectly as I needed.

Comment: @paolo so the generic overload doesn't give you a `tuple<tuple<...>>`. Not needed in this case

Comment: Shouldn't tuple version be `return std::apply([](auto... args) { return std::tuple_cat(flatten(args)...);}, tup);`?

Comment: @Jarod42 probably. I'm working on a C++20 version that uses a [`tuple_like` concept](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68443804/c20-concept-to-check-tuple-like-types)