# How to write a concept that checks for an inner type in all the types of a std::tuple?

Tags: c++, metaprogramming, c++20, c++-concepts

Continuing with my studies on C++ 20 concepts, I am trying to write a `concept` that would assure that every type in a `std::tuple` has inner type defined with a specific name, and that all the `inner`s have the same type.

I tried this:

```
#include <concepts>
#include <string>
#include <tuple>

template <typename t>
concept type_model = requires(t p_t) {
  typename t::inner;
};

template <typename t, typename u>
concept same_inner = requires(t p_t, u p_u) {
  std::is_same_v<typename t::inner, typename u::inner>;
};

template <typename t, typename... t_type_model>
concept container_model = requires(t p_t) {

  requires((same_inner<t_type_model,
                       std::tuple_element_t<0, std::tuple<t_type_model...>>> &&
            ...));
};

struct type_1 {
  using inner = int;
};

struct type_2 {
  using inner = std::string;
};

template <type_model... t_type_models> struct container {};

template <type_model... t_type_model>
void f(container_model<t_type_model...> auto) {}

using containers_X = container<type_1, type_2>;

int main() {

  containers_X _x;

  f(_x);

  return 0;
}
```

I expected an error of concept not satisfied because `type_1::inner` and `type_2::inner` have different types, but no errors were reported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code,

```cpp
template <typename t, typename... t_type_model>
concept container_model = requires(t p_t) {

  requires((same_inner<t_type_model,
                       std::tuple_element_t<0, std::tuple<t_type_model...>>> &&
            ...));
};
```

does not actually test the condition within the second requires clause.

The correct formulation is

```cpp
template <typename t, typename u>
concept same_inner = std::is_same_v<typename t::inner, typename u::inner>;
```

or,

```cpp
template <typename t, typename u>
concept same_inner = requires (t i, u j) {
    requires (std::same_as<typename t::inner, typename u::inner>);
};
```

This has tripped me up in the past.

**Update**

The `container_model` concept

```cpp
template <typename t, typename... t_type_model>
concept container_model = requires(t p_t) {

  requires((same_inner<t_type_model,
                       std::tuple_element_t<0, std::tuple<t_type_model...>>> &&
            ...));
};
```

need to be something like

```cpp
template <typename t, typename... t_type_model>
concept container_model = (same_inner<t, t_type_model> && ...);
```

At this point, the following assertions should hold:

```
static_assert(not same_inner<type_1, type_2>);
static_assert(not container_model<type_1, type_2>);
```

When the function `f` is invoked, it is passed `container<type_1, type_2>` which qualifies as a `container_model` because it gets translated to `container_model<container<type_t, type_2>>` which returns `true`.

One possible fix is to change `f` to something like

```cpp
template <type_model... t_type_model>
void f(container_model<container<t_type_model...>> auto) {}
```

### Summary

Just to be clear, here is all the code with changes and this code fails to compile because the `container_model` constraints are not satisfied.

```cpp
#include <concepts>
#include <string>
#include <tuple>

template <typename t>
concept type_model = requires(t p_t) {
  typename t::inner;
};

template <typename t, typename u>
concept same_inner = std::is_same_v<typename std::decay_t<t>::inner,
                                    typename std::decay_t<u>::inner>;

template <typename t, typename... t_type_model>
concept container_model = (same_inner<t, t_type_model> && ...);

struct type_1 {
  using inner = int;
};

struct type_2 {
  using inner = std::string;
};

template <type_model... t_type_models> struct container {};

template <type_model... t_type_model>
void f(container_model<container<t_type_model...>> auto) {}

using containers_X = container<type_1, type_2>;

static_assert(not same_inner<type_1, type_2>);
static_assert(not container_model<type_1, type_2>);

int main() {

  containers_X _x;

  f(_x);

  return 0;
}
```

## **New Update**

The previous update was incomplete at best. Here is the latest code which I believe enforces the desired concepts.

### Sample Code

```cpp
#include <concepts>
#include <string>
#include <tuple>

// Does T have an inner type named `inner`.
template<class T>
concept Inner = requires(T x) {
    typename T::inner;
};

// Do T and U have same inner type.
template<class T, class U>
concept SameInner = Inner<T> and Inner<U> and std::is_same_v<typename T::inner, typename U::inner>;

// Helper for checking that all template parameters satisfy Inner
// concept and all pairs satisfy SameInner.
template<typename>
struct inner_container_impl : std::false_type {};

template<template<typename...> class Tp, Inner T>
struct inner_container_impl<Tp<T>> {
    static constexpr bool value = true;
};

template<template<typename...> class Tp, Inner T, Inner... Ts>
struct inner_container_impl<Tp<T, Ts...>> {
    static constexpr bool value = (SameInner<T, Ts> and ...);
};

// The concept just use the helper.
template<class T>
concept InnerContainer = inner_container_impl<T>::value;

// Test types.
struct type_1 {
    using inner = int;
};

struct type_2 {
    using inner = std::string;
};

struct type_3 {
    using inner = int;
};

template<Inner... Ts> struct container {};

void f(InnerContainer auto) {}

using containers_X = std::tuple<type_1, type_2>;
using containers_Y = std::tuple<type_1, type_3>;

static_assert(not SameInner<type_1, type_2>);
static_assert(not InnerContainer<std::tuple<type_1, type_2>>);
static_assert(not InnerContainer<containers_X>);

int main() {

    containers_X _x;
    f(_x);

    containers_Y _y;
    f(_y);

  return 0;
}
```

### Output

```
/work/so/scratch/src/p4.cpp:64:5: error: no matching
      function for call to 'f'
    f(_x);
    ^
/work/so/scratch/src/p4.cpp:52:6: note: candidate
      template ignored: constraints not satisfied [with auto:1 = std::tuple<type_1,
      type_2>]
void f(InnerContainer auto) {}
     ^
/work/so/scratch/src/p4.cpp:52:8: note: because
      'std::tuple<type_1, type_2>' does not satisfy 'InnerContainer'
void f(InnerContainer auto) {}
       ^
/work/so/scratch/src/p4.cpp:35:26: note: because
      'inner_container_impl<tuple<type_1, type_2> >::value' evaluated to false
concept InnerContainer = inner_container_impl<T>::value;
                         ^
1 error generated.
```

Comment: I tried both forms, but the compile is still not reporting any errors, Maybe there is something wrong in `container_model`?

Comment: Yes, I see. There are two moe issues. I will update my answer.

Comment: I see what is wrong, but I would like to avoid having to use `container_model<container<t_type_model...>>`. I wonder if there is a way to define `container_model` so that I could pass to `f` a `std::tuple<type_1, type_2>`. I mean, `container_model` would exist just to make sure that all the types in a `std::tuple` satisfy `same_inner`.

Comment: I changed  to `using containers_X = container<type_1, type_1>;` and the following errors were reported: 
`line 39: No matching function for call to 'f'`

`line 28: candidate template ignored: constraints not satisfied [with t_type_model = <>, auto:2 = containers_X]`

`line 28: because 'container_model<container<type_1, type_1>, container<> >' evaluated to false`

`line 15: because 'same_inner<container<type_1, type_1>, container<> >' evaluated to false`

`line 11: because substituted constraint expression is ill-formed: no type named 'inner' in 'container<type_1, type_1>'`

Comment: That update was clearly incorrect on my part -- I guess it was too late for me to be writing code. I added another update -- I rewrote the code more in my style so that I could understand it better -- you should be able to translate it back pretty easily. I think this latest version enforces the concepts as you intended.

Comment: Congratulations! The very elegant last version works gracefully

Answer (score 2):

Your concept `same_inner` have no effect and can be compiled with any types.

You should use `same_as` concept in your
`same_inner` concept restriction, instead of `is_same`, which always compiles successfully and you cound fetch the result from.

```cpp
template<typename T, typename U>
concept same_inner = same_as<typename T::inner, typename U::inner>;
```

This may fix the problem.

See [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts/same_as) for detailed informations.

Comment: I believe the correct code is `template<typename T, typename U> concept same_inner = same_as<typename T::inner, typename U::inner>;`, but still no errors were reported by the compiler.

Comment: @canellas You are right, my apology. Omitting typename is a Microsoft Extension, not in cpp standard. Answer edited.

Answer (score 0):

Besides @[RandomBits](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1202808/randombits) implementation, I believe I found another one:

```
#include <concepts>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <tuple>

template <typename t>
concept has_inner = requires(t p_t) {
  typename t::inner;
};

template <has_inner t_1, has_inner t_2> struct same_inner {
  static constexpr bool yes{
      std::is_same_v<typename t_1::inner, typename t_2::inner>};
};

template <typename t_tuple, size_t t_idx = std::tuple_size_v<t_tuple> - 1>
struct check_if_all_has_inner {
  static constexpr bool yes{
      same_inner<typename std::tuple_element_t<t_idx, t_tuple>,
                 typename std::tuple_element_t<t_idx - 1, t_tuple>>::yes &&
      check_if_all_has_inner<t_tuple, t_idx - 1>::yes};
};

template <typename t_tuple> struct check_if_all_has_inner<t_tuple, 0> {
  static constexpr bool yes{true};
};

template <typename t_tuple>
concept container_model = (std::tuple_size_v<t_tuple> > 0) &&
                          (check_if_all_has_inner<t_tuple>::yes);

struct type_1 {
  using inner = int;
};

struct type_2 {
  using inner = std::string;
};

struct type_3 {
  using inner = std::string;
};

struct type_4 {};

void f(container_model auto) {}

int main() {

  /// ERROR 1 if code below uncommented
  //  f(std::tuple<type_1, type_2>{});

  f(std::tuple<type_2, type_3>{});

  {
    std::cout << std::boolalpha
              << check_if_all_has_inner<std::tuple<type_1, type_2>>::yes
              << std::endl;
  }

  {
    std::cout << std::boolalpha
              << check_if_all_has_inner<std::tuple<type_3, type_2>>::yes
              << std::endl;
  }

  ///   ERROR 2 if code below uncommented
  //  {
  //    std::cout << std::boolalpha
  //              << check_if_all_has_inner<std::tuple<type_3, type_2,
  //              type_4>>::yes
  //              << std::endl;
  //  }

  return 0;
}
```

Where `ERROR 1` is

```
main.cpp:52:3: No matching function for call to 'f'
main.cpp:47:6: candidate template ignored: constraints not satisfied [with
auto:1 = std::tuple<type_1, type_2>] main.cpp:47:8: because 'std::tuple<type_1,
type_2>' does not satisfy 'container_model' main.cpp:31:28: because
'check_if_all_has_inner<tuple<type_1, type_2> >::yes' evaluated to false
```

and `ERROR 2` is

```
main.cpp:71:78: In instantiation of static data member
'check_if_all_has_inner<std::tuple<type_3, type_2, type_4>, 2>::yes' requested
here main.cpp:20:7: In instantiation of static data member
'check_if_all_has_inner<std::tuple<type_3, type_2, type_4>, 2>::yes' requested
here

main.cpp:20:7: Constraints not satisfied for class template 'same_inner' [with
t_1 = type_4, t_2 = type_2] main.cpp:71:78: in instantiation of static data
member 'check_if_all_has_inner<std::tuple<type_3, type_2, type_4>, 2>::yes'
requested here main.cpp:12:11: because 'type_4' does not satisfy 'has_inner'
main.cpp:9:15: because 'typename t::inner' would be invalid: no type named
'inner' in 'type_4'
```

Answer (score 0):

[RandomBits](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1202808/randombits), based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68443804/c20-concept-to-check-tuple-like-types) topic, I think I came up with another implentation:

```
#include <concepts>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>

// checking if a type is a std::tuple
template <class t_tuple, std::size_t t_idx>
concept has_tuple_element = requires(t_tuple t) {
  typename std::tuple_element_t<t_idx, std::remove_const_t<t_tuple>>;
  {
    get<t_idx>(t)
    } -> std::convertible_to<const std::tuple_element_t<t_idx, t_tuple> &>;
};

template <class t_tuple>
concept tuple_like = !std::is_reference_v<t_tuple> && requires(t_tuple t) {
  typename std::tuple_size<t_tuple>::type;
  requires std::derived_from<
      std::tuple_size<t_tuple>,
      std::integral_constant<std::size_t, std::tuple_size_v<t_tuple>>>;
}
&&[]<std::size_t... t_idx>(std::index_sequence<t_idx...>) {
  return (has_tuple_element<t_tuple, t_idx> && ...);
}
(std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size_v<t_tuple>>());

// checking if a type in a index of a tuple has 'inner' type, if the index
// before it has a 'inner' type, and if both 'inner' types are identical
template <size_t t_idx, typename t_tuple> struct same_inner {
  static constexpr bool yes{
      std::is_same_v<typename std::tuple_element_t<t_idx, t_tuple>::inner,
                     typename std::tuple_element_t<t_idx - 1, t_tuple>::inner>};
};

template <typename t_tuple> struct same_inner<0, t_tuple> {
  static constexpr bool yes{true};
};

// std::tuple where all the types have a 'inner' type
template <typename t_tuple>
concept container_model = (tuple_like<t_tuple>)&&[]<std::size_t... t_idx>(
    std::index_sequence<t_idx...>) {
  return (same_inner<t_idx, t_tuple>::yes && ...);
}
(std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size_v<t_tuple>>());

// examples
struct type_1 {
  using inner = int;
};

struct type_2 {
  using inner = std::string;
};

struct type_3 {
  using inner = std::string;
};

struct type_4 {};

// function that will handle a std::tuple where all the types have a 'inner'
// type
void f(container_model auto) {}

int main() {

  f(std::tuple<type_2, type_3>{});

  /// ERROR if code below uncommented
  //  f(std::tuple<type_1, type_2>{});

  /// ERROR if code below uncommented
  //   f(std::tuple<type_2, type_4>{});

  /// ERROR if code below uncommented
  //  f(int{3});

  return 0;
}
```