# Ambiguous call for template functions with concepts

Tags: c++, c++-concepts, ambiguous

With this code below:

```
#define P std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n'

template <typename ... arg_pack> concept is_tuple = requires(std::tuple<arg_pack ...>) { true; };
template <typename ... arg_pack> concept is_variant = requires(std::variant<arg_pack ...>) { true; };

template <is_tuple type_t> void X(const type_t &t) { P; }     // A
//template <is_variant type_t> void X(const type_t &v) { P; } // B
void X(int) { P; }

int main()
{
    std::tuple<int> t;
    std::variant<int> v;

    X(t);
    X(v);
    X(0);

    return 0;
}
```

I'm getting [<kbd>this output</kbd>](https://godbolt.org/z/onPx8GPGx):

> ```
> void X(const type_t &) [type_t = std::tuple<int>]
> void X(const type_t &) [type_t = std::variant<int>]
> void X(int)
> ```

Uncommenting the line marked with `B` comment, the compiler reports ambiguity:

```
error: call to 'X' is ambiguous
    X(t);
    ^
note: candidate function [with type_t = std::tuple<int>]
template <is_tuple type_t> void X(const type_t &t) { P; }
                                ^
note: candidate function [with type_t = std::tuple<int>]
template <is_variant type_t> void X(const type_t &v) { P; }
                                  ^
error: call to 'X' is ambiguous
    X(v);
    ^
note: candidate function [with type_t = std::variant<int>]
template <is_tuple type_t> void X(const type_t &t) { P; }
                                ^
note: candidate function [with type_t = std::variant<int>]
template <is_variant type_t> void X(const type_t &v) { P; }
                                  ^
2 errors generated.
```

This is very confusing.

- Why calling `X` with `B` line commented doesn't report a compiler error but calls the incorrect function?
- Why calling `X` with `B` line uncommented is abiguous considering that `std::is_same_v<std::tuple<int>, std::variant<int>>` is false?

---

Thanks Jan Schultke and SO community, I've managed to workaround a simple `is_tuple` and `is_variant` with your help:

```
template <typename type_t>
concept is_tuple = []<typename ... arg_pack>(std::tuple<arg_pack ...>){ return true; }(type_t{});

template <typename type_t>
concept is_variant = []<typename ... arg_pack>(std::variant<arg_pack ...>){ return true; }(type_t{});
```

[<kbd>Wokring demo</kbd>](https://godbolt.org/z/PYvsnjhT9).

Comment: For the tuple `X` template, the `type_t` will be `std::variant<int>`. And the `arg_pack` in the concept will be equal to `std::variant<int>`. So the `requires` check will check that `std::tuple<std::variant<int>>` works. Which it does.

Comment: both `is_tuple` and `is_variant` concepts definitely don't work the way you expect them to.

Comment: You might add some tests for your concept, such as `static_assert(!is_tuple<int>); static_assert(is_tuple<std::tuple<int>>)` to reduce the problem origin (and so you will see that your concept is wrong).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The call is ambiguous because you're misusing concepts, and both your concepts are effectively `concept C = true;`

In the concept:

> ```cpp
> template <typename ... arg_pack>
> concept is_tuple = requires(std::tuple<arg_pack ...>) { true; };
> ```

... the `std::tuple<arg_pack>` isn't verifying that you somehow have a `std::tuple`; the `std::tuple<arg_pac>` is like an unused function parameter in the requires expression.

The type constraint `<is_tuple type_t>` requires `is_tuple<type_t>`, which expands to:

```cpp
requires (std::tuple<my_type>) { true; } // always true
```

Ideally, you should create a concept for a *tuple-like* type, or a *variant-like* type. This is what the C++ standard library commonly does, and such concepts exists in the C++ standard, although they are exposition-only. See also: [C++20 Concept to check tuple-like types](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68443804/5740428)

With a *tuple-like* concept, you will be much more flexible, and you can accept types like `std::array`, `std::pair`, etc. instead of just `std::tuple`.