# How to constraint a function for pair-like objects?

Tags: c++, constraints, c++20, c++-concepts

In C++20, I need to implement a static function `key()` that takes a const reference to an object and returns a const reference to the key. Since the object can be a key itself or a key-value pair, the function has been implemented in the following way:

```cpp
template <typename K>
static const K& key(const K& x) noexcept
{ return x; }

template <pair-like P>
static const K& key(const P& x) noexcept
{ return std::get<0>(x); }
```

Is there a way to constraint the second function overload in order that it accept only a [pair-like](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tuple-like) object as an argument?

Comment: Just change the second overload to `template <typename K, typename V>
static const K& key(const std::pair<K, V>& x)`  ??

Comment: @user12002570, the issue is that, if P is not a `std::pair` object, a temporary object may be constructed.

Comment: `requires requires(const P x) { { std::get<0>(x) } -> std::convertible_to<K>; }`?

Comment: [C++20 Concept to check tuple-like types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68443804/c20-concept-to-check-tuple-like-types)

Comment: What if your key is a pair? Like `std::map<std::pair<int, int>, std::string>`?